# Header not being shown completely

Tags: header-footer

I made the following book document with a small page.  I discovered a problem, that the header in not being shown completely.  What can I do ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\usepackage{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand \wvPage {}
  %% 31x21 cm Page Size
  {
    \geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
               textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
               left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm}
  }

\wvPage

\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Ramanujan}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter {This is an introduction to some topic}

\section{Test}

Some text

\subsection{A Subsection}

More text here

\subsubsection{A Subsubection}

And more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would not place arbitrary code inside an `expl3` block: you could load `geometry` and set the keys without that at all.

Comment: You realize that top, bottom and textheight add up to more than paperheight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should insert de command `includehead`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\usepackage{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand \wvPage {}
%% 31x21 cm Page Size
{
    \geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
        textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
        left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm, includehead}
}

\wvPage

\ExplSyntaxOff

\title{Sections and Chapters}
\author{Ramanujan}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter {This is an introduction to some topic}
    
    \section{Test}
    
    Some text
    
    \subsection{A Subsection}
    
    More text here
    
    \subsubsection{A Subsubection}
    
    And more text
    
\end{document}
```